# Matplotlib plot first n entrys trough value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
phones['phone_brand'].value_counts().plot('bar')
plt.show()
```

I just want to plot the first 20 entries. There are two possibilities in my opinion. I do only the first 20 entries count or I do only the first 20 entries to plot. I need only the first 20 entries of the whole list. Thanks for the inspiration!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give back the top 20 value from `value_counts`

```
phones['phone_brand'].value_counts().head(20).plot('bar')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Its more compact as my answer. Can you pls send me the reference of this solution?

Comment: @harun https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html

Comment: Would it be possible to add another column that includes the sum of everything that is not included in head(20)?

Answer (score 0):

```
vl_list = phones["phone_brand"].value_counts()

vl_list[0:20].plot('bar')
plt.show()
```

The solution is as follows: The DataFrame count method returns a pandas series. These can then be easily reached with an index [0:19]. So I then only enter this index as .plot() and it works.

Comment: vl_list[0:19] should it be [0:20]?